# Gave the wrong ABI to etherscan.io and I need to send a new one

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, etherscan

The contract is already verified and published but I need to give a different ABI. However I can't reverify the contract.

Answer (score 0):

EtherScan verification works on source code, not ABI files.

If your contract source code changes, you recompile the smart contract and redeploy it and reverify the new version.